# `yarn remove` a list of deps without bailing on an error

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Is it possible to run `yarn remove a b c` without stopping because dependency `a` is not in your local `package.json`?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/fcf6298d8feb10d6d92d17bf4f5d416c33716faf/src/cli/commands/remove.js#L74) I'd say no. I think the quickest way to get where you want is to remove `yarn.lock`, run `yarn install` and _then_ `yarn rm b c`

Comment: I ended up using a bash for loop with remove to simulate this.

Comment: Out of interest, wouldn't that leave the `a` package in the `yarn.lock` file? Or maybe it wasn't there to begin with?

Comment: It won't. `add` and `remove` save by default, which npm might do now as well.